# android: How to acess a single or multiple Mediaplayer instance when going back to previous page

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have three buttons with Play symbols (on press changes to pause and viceversa).

On clicking each play symbol, it will play an audio file. The play symbol turns to pause.

On clicking pause symbol the audio file will pause.

for each button I have a mediaplayer variable:

```
Mediaplayer media1, media2, media3
```

So i have the code for playing when onclick play button:

```
if(media1 == null){
    media1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(context.getExternalFilesDir("krishna").getPath() + "/1.mp3"));
media1.start()
}
```

If i go back from this page, how to access the media1 variable. So that i want to put a button there to pause it.

If i started all three audio files at a time. If I go back how to access media1, media2, media3 seperately.

Answer (score 0):

One way of achieving this is to make the `media` object a `public static` one.

So instead of `Mediaplayer media1, media2, media3`, you can create a class that makes a static definition of the mediaplayers, e.g.

```
    public class Mediaplayers{
Context context;
  Mediaplayers(Context context){
     this.context = context;
```

}

```
 public static MediaPlayer media1 = MediaPlayer.create(context, Uri.parse(context.getExternalFilesDir("krishna").getPath() + "/1.mp3"));
```

//blah blah blah
}